# Check if user input is true or false

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a simple game in C# winforms. But I'm having trouble. In my game the user needs to press tiles, there are 3 gray and 1 black tiles. If the user presses the black tile they can continue if they press a gray tile they "die" and have to start over.

I'm having trouble with checking if the user pressed the tile or not. At the moment i use a boolean that get set to true if the user pressed the tile. In my timer i check if that boolean is true or false, if its true the method to generate 4 random tiles gets called. And if its false (which it is by default) the user gets the same message as they were to get when they hit a gray tile. here is my code:

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int temp = 0;

        if (temp != 3)
        {
            temp++;
            label8.Text = temp.ToString();
            RandomPanel();
        }
        else
        {
            if (Clicked == false)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("You lost! Care to try again?");
                button1.Show();
            }
            else if (Clicked == true)
            {
                RandomPanel();
                Clicked = false;
            }
        }
```

and this is my code for when you press a tile:

```
private void PbRow1_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PbRow1_1.Tag == "Black")
        {
            Clicked = true;
            int temp1 = Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text);
            int temp2 = Convert.ToInt32(label3.Text);

            if (temp1 <= temp2)
            {
                int temp = temp1 += 1;
                label3.Text = temp.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                label3.Text = label1.Text;
            }
            Score += 1;
            label1.Text = Score.ToString();
        }
        else if (PbRow1_1.Tag == "Gray")
        {
            Clicked = false;
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("You lost! Care to try again?");
            button1.Show();
        }
    }
```

If you wonder why i use the:

```
int temp
```

In my
    Timer_tick event thats because my form needs to generate 3 diffrent combinations of pannels before the user can play. as seen in the picture below:

http://prntscr.com/3lwj1g

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `int temp = 0; if (temp != 3)...` temp will always be 0

Comment: Any help for what exactly? You included the context and the code but no question..

Comment: Whats your question / whats the problem?

Comment: I need to find a way to check if the user pressed the tile. Which I can't figure out.

Comment: Pressed in how? mouse over mouse click a character you're moving with the arrow keys?

Comment: mouse_click but @JohnnyMopp fixed my problem. thanks for that

Comment: I'd get rid of the timer, disable PbRow1_1 until you've loaded the panels, and just use the handler

Comment: I'm still in the process of trying once I get it working the way I want I'll start tweaking and use your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this with the help of Johhny mop.
I was having this issue because my

```
int temp = 0;
```

was in my timer_tick event.